# how can I temporarily pause other threads using boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have a program with 2 threads (A and B). Is it possible to define a block of code in thread B, which once entered pauses thread A until the block has finished executing?

I am using C++ and the library boost::thread 1.44

EDIT: The problem I had, which prevented me from just using a mutex was that I did not have access to the code in thread A as it's a non-thread-safe library, so I could not control when it accessed my shared resource. I have made some architectural changes to my code and now the resource is no longer shared and the problem is solved.

Comment: What if thread A is holding a lock that is required by thread B?

Comment: @Mike daniels, good point! I have rearchitected my code so I am able to use a mutex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the `scoped_lock/mutex` solution of Grammin you can use a [condition variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) (perhaps a more common idiom for your problem) or even a [barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers).

Answer (score 4):

This is called locking and in boost you would want to use scoped_lock

Check this page out: [scoped_lock](http://developer-resource.blogspot.com/2009/01/boost-scoped-lock.html)